# How to resolve this error in QtCreator? Execution failed. Command failed

Tags: c++, qt-creator

When I set a breakpoint in the program and run it in the debug, I get this error. Please tell me how to fix it. Run in Terminal mode selected
[image]

Comment: Your problem is with Qt-Creator not the Qt framework.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure QtCreator's GDB experimental functions are disabled, as they may cause unexpected debugger's behaviour.
Those are located under: **QtCreator -> Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> GDB Extended**

[GDB Extended Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCtOs.png)